# how to interact with a Wiegand RFID reader/writer?

Tags: rfid

Guess we have a RFID reader that can read a card number, these readers can connect to pc using RS232 or USB cable and so on. how i can interact with this device. in simple scenario i want to read the card no when reader read a card.

- any OS (but windows is preferred)
- any Programming Language (but c# and other .net languages is
  preferred)

Answer (score 0):

Its Very easy with programming in Wiegand.

Use .Net Serial port communication to send and receive the data.

find the [datasheet and command sets](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/Wiegand%20rfid-datasheet.html) are available.

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

1. How to capture the card number from the returning data. see this [code](http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/CreditCardSwipeMagneticStripProcessing).
2. How to interact with the Device, if USB Device see this [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468895(v=vs.85).aspx),or serial Device use system.windows.IO.serial port class.